# Open links in Outlook from one domain in Firefox, the rest in IE

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook

Is this even possible?

We are packaging a Firefox bundle to handle links to Salesforce.com

We'd love it if links in Outlook to Salesforce.com could be opened in the Firefox bundle, while keeping other links opening in the default IE8.

If this is possible, I'd love to know how. My google skills have been bested by the problem :[

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36/)'s site filter setting it to `/^.*^[salesforce\.com].*$/` which if my regular expression knowledge is correct should send all sites except for salesforce.com into IETab mode.

Not exactly IE, but in a good way. :-)